# Evaluate multiple metrics with GridSearcCv

Tags: python

I am trying to optimize some models, in this case the Kneighbors, and I would like to evaluate three metrics which are "accuracy" "recall" and "f1-score"; the program gives me an error in the fit function. Know how to help me ??

the code is:

```
model=KNeighborsClassifier()

data=pd.read_excel("fast SLA NON SLA3.xlsx",header=0) #6 metaboliti
data1=data.drop(['Campioni','Background','Genotype','SLA','NONSLA'],axis=1) 
scaler=MinMaxScaler()  #diventa array
scaled=scaler.fit_transform(data1)
etichette=data['Genotype'].to_numpy().ravel()
etichette = label_binarize(etichette, classes=['NTG','G93A'])
etichette = np.ravel(etichette)

cv=model_selection.RepeatedStratifiedKFold(6, 10, random_state=42)

metriche=['accuracy','recall','f1']

grid=dict() #creo un dizionario
a = [l for l in range(1,7)]
grid['n_neighbors']=a
grid['weights']=['uniform','distance']
grid['algorithm']=['auto','ball_tree','kd_tree','brute']

search=GridSearchCV(model, grid, scoring= metriche, cv=cv, n_jobs=-1,refit=str)
risultati=search.fit(scaled,etichette)


print('Mean: %.3f' % risultati.best_score_)
print('Config: %s' % risultati.best_params_)
```

this line "**risultati=search.fit(scaled,etichette)**" give me some problems.

this is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-76a738b1afcd> in <module>()
     21 
     22 search=GridSearchCV(model, grid, scoring= metriche, cv=cv, n_jobs=-1,refit=str)
---> 23 risultati=search.fit(scaled,etichette)
     24 
     25 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    719                 self.best_index_ = self.refit(results)
    720                 if not isinstance(self.best_index_, numbers.Integral):
--> 721                     raise TypeError('best_index_ returned is not an integer')
    722                 if (self.best_index_ < 0 or
    723                    self.best_index_ >= len(results["params"])):



 TypeError: best_index_ returned is not an integer
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! If you're getting an error, please [edit] your question to include the full error traceback, as that contains valuable information on what the actual problem is

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. I modified the question.

Comment: Thank you for updating, but the error message doesn't appear to contain the final line(s) that tell the actual error being thrown

Comment: thank you, I updated the question with the error. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

search=GridSearchCV(model, grid, scoring= metriche, cv=cv, n_jobs=-1,refit=str)

set bool Flase for refit instead of str.

Like,
search=GridSearchCV(model, grid, scoring= metriche, cv=cv, n_jobs=-1,refit=Flase)

By default refit is set to bool True.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. If i set refit=False I have another error in the line "print('Mean: %.3f' % risultati.best_score_)", the error said "GridSearchCv object has no attribute 'best_score_'. I don't understand why this message comes because in the GridSearchCv Sklearn it told me to use "best score" to display the best result.